# How to retrieve memory addresses vmalloc()ed previously by any modules?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, vmalloc

First, vmalloc() called many times by any modules. Some of those addresses have be freed, some have not been freed, and some are leaking.

Then, a module driver needs to detect those addresses' status, i.e. are those addresses freed, not freed or leaking?

The driver needs to retrieve those addresses. Do you know where those addresses are, and how to retrieve them?

Comment: you can check how kmemleak doing this